# Python Dash live update with dcc.Interval not working

Tags: python, websocket, plotly-dash

I am trying to update a Dash chart opened in my web browser with datas coming from a websocket server I made.
I have no issue with the websocket part. My server sends to the client datas that I add to a list and convert this list to a pandas DataFrame object. Then this object is added to a multiprocess.Queue.

In my Dash callback from dcc.Interval, I get the data from the previous Queue (this part seems to work because I can print correctly the data) and update my Graph.

But the Graph in my browser is not updating. I do not see any error raised in my python code or in the browser console. (I tried with Firefox, Chrome and Brave)
My python console print  `dash-update-component HTTP/1.1" 200 -` with my data at each callback interval and the tab name is `Updating...`
Worse, sometimes I can see one or 10 datas correctly displayed then nothing without changing the code, just by restarting my code...

Here the code (client side) :

```
import multiprocess as mp
import threading
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from socket import *
import time
import json
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


FLAG_QUIT = False  
FLAG_ASK_DATA = False

MAX_SIZE = 10

queue = mp.Queue()
datas = []


app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H4('Live Chart'),
        dcc.Graph(id='live-update-graph', animate =True), 
        dcc.Interval(
            id='interval-component',
            interval=200,
            n_intervals=0
        )
    ]
)

@app.callback(Output('live-update-graph', 'figure'),
              [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')])
def update_graph(n):
    df = queue.get()
    print(df)
    fig = go.Scatter(x=df.index, y = df['Data'])
    return fig

    

# function for receiving message from client
def send_to_server(clsock):
    global FLAG_QUIT
    global FLAG_ASK_DATA
    while True:
        try:
            if FLAG_QUIT == True:
                break
        
            if FLAG_ASK_DATA:
                time.sleep(0.5)
                clsock.sendall("ok".encode())
        except Exception as ex:
            print(str(ex))
        

# function for receiving message from server
def recv_from_server(clsock):
    global FLAG_QUIT
    global FLAG_ASK_DATA
    while True:
        try:
            data = clsock.recv(1024).decode()
            if data == 'q':
                print('Closing connection')
                FLAG_QUIT = True
                break
            process_data(data)
            FLAG_ASK_DATA = True
        except Exception as ex:
            print(str(ex))
        

def process_data(data):
    global datas
    global queue
    process_websocket_data(data)
    datas_dataframe = convert_data_to_dataframe(datas)
    queue.put(datas_dataframe)

def convert_data_to_dataframe(data):
    data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data)
    data_frame = data_frame.drop_duplicates(0)
    data_frame_date = data_frame[0]

    final_date = []

    for time in data_frame_date.unique():
        readable = datetime.strptime(time, '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M')
        final_date.append(readable)

    data_frame.pop(0)
    dataframe_final_date = pd.DataFrame(final_date)

    dataframe_final_date.columns = ['Date']

    final_dataframe = data_frame.join(dataframe_final_date)

    final_dataframe.set_index('Date', inplace = True)

    final_dataframe.columns = ['Data']
    return final_dataframe

def process_websocket_data(raw_data):
    data_json = json.loads(raw_data)
    data = [data_json['Date'],data_json['Data']]
    datas.append(data)
    while len(datas) > MAX_SIZE:
        datas.pop(0)


def main():
    threads = []
    HOST = 'localhost'
    PORT = 8765
    clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    connected = False
    while not connected:
        try:
            print("Waiting connecting server...")
            time.sleep(1)
            clientSocket.connect((HOST, PORT))
            connected = True
        except :
            pass
    
    print('Client is connected to a chat sever!\n')
    clientSocket.send('start'.encode())

    t_send = threading.Thread(target=send_to_server, args=(clientSocket,))
    t_rcv = threading.Thread(target=recv_from_server, args=(clientSocket,))


    t_send.start()
    t_rcv.start()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    app.run_server()
```

What did I code wrong or miss?

**Edit :**
This is the datas I get from the queue in the callback update_graph(n) method.

```
                Data
Date
2019-09-16  10302.00
2019-09-23   8061.98
2019-09-30   8042.08
2019-10-07   7851.01
2019-10-14   8274.33
2019-10-21   8218.23
2019-10-28   9534.37
2019-11-04   9197.86
2019-11-11   9041.31
2019-11-18   8504.13
```

I also tried to replace my X axis by a list of int instead of a list of dates but the result is the same. No refreshing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd bet it's because your interval is way too fast. 200ms is probably not enough time for the network request and the callback to finish before the next interval fires off, which restarts the callback. Try setting it to something like 20000 (20s) to start off, and see if it works, then tune it carefully to see how fast  you can reliably get it to run.

Comment: @coralvanda Thank you for your response. Unfortunately I tried with a bigger interval as you suggested but the result is the same : no refresh in my browser. Maybe the way I tried to implement my application is totally wrong. I am not familiar with Dash.

Comment: If you debug, or add some `print` statements, can you see what your data frame looks like during the callback? That might help direct the solution.

Comment: @coralvanda I edited my post with the datas I get in the callback and a test I did but it did not work.

Comment: Ok, so you have the data, that's good. Something about how you're setting up the Scatter plot could be the issue. You could try hard-coding a test df to play with. Also, you could try setting `figure={}` in the layout for the `dcc.Graph`, because sometimes having no prop defined acts funny.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed to find the problem and it seems to be the Queue in the callback. So I removed the queue mechanism and instead use a classic list with a lock.

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id="live_graph", animate=False),
    dcc.Interval(id='interval_component',
                interval=INTERVAL,
               
    )])


@app.callback(Output('live_graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('interval_component', 'n_intervals')])
def update_graph(num):
    global datas_dataframe
    
    lock.acquire()
    if len(datas_dataframe) == 0:
        print("No data")
        lock.release()
        return no_update

    try:
        df = datas_dataframe.pop(0)
        fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter(x=df.index,y=df['Data'])],
                        layout=go.Layout(yaxis=dict(tickfont=dict(size=22))))

        lock.release()
        return fig
    except Exception as ex:
        print(str(ex))
        lock.release()
        return no_update
```